# How to profit from frequent air trips home?

Tags: business

If you travel light, you can use the extra luggage space to transport items from your country of residence to sell in your home country, and vice versa.

Are there other ways to profit from frequent international air travel?

Comment: Keep in mind that if you are bringing things into a country with the express intention of selling them, you will most likely have to pay import duty on them. The duty free allowances are generally for personal use items only.

Comment: If you don't tell customs, I won't ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it advocates illegal behavior.

Comment: @fkraiem My comment advocates illegal behavior, but the question is clean. Is there a community rule against cheeky comments?

Comment: This question might still be more relevant on Travel.SE